# Jupyterhub authenticator “invalid username or password” with users that are clearly valid

Tags: python, authentication, jupyterhub

Obs: this question is duplicated [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/authenticator-invalid-username-or-password-with-users-that-are-clearly-valid/14135).

Hello all. Im configuring a jupyterhub server in an ubuntu machine. According to [this](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started/authenticators-users-basics.html) page, not setting a specific c.Authenticator.allowed_users will automatically set to default and allow for all authenticated users.
My server does not have any c.Authenticator.allowed_users property set, however it displays “Invalid username or password” to some users that exist in the domain and can, for example, ssh into the server machine.

Do i need to set any specific configuration that im not aware of?

If it helps, my machine gets a lot of info about authenticated users from the domain, so not everything is stored locally. For example,

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

results in a short list of users info while

```
getent passwd
```

Results in a much longer list. Is this affecting my server somehow?

Invalid login screen:

[image]

Server configuration code:

```
c.JupyterHub.bind_url = 'http://:8000/jupyter'
c.JupyterHub.pid_file = '/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub.pid'
c.JupyterHub.shutdown_on_logout = True
c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = 'lnlsSpawner.spawner.spawner'
c.Spawner.env_keep = ['PATH', 'PYTHONPATH', 'CONDA_ROOT', 'CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV', 'VIRTUAL_ENV', 'LANG', 'LC_ALL', 'PYDM_DEFAULT_PROTOCOL', 'EPICS_CA_ADDR_LIST']
c.Spawner.notebook_dir = '~/' #Added for testing. Should be removed?
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is obviously not ideal, but worked for me. Since i tried some of the class Authenticator methods and nothing more direct worked, i added:

```
names = subprocess.check_output(["getent","passwd"])
names=names.decode()
names=names.split("\n")
for i in range(0,len(names)):
    names[i]=names[i].split(":")[0]
names=set(names)
c.Authenticator.allowed_users = names
```

To the jupyterhub configuration file. So now it gets all users from getent passwd and allows them to log.

Suggestions on better solutions would still be welcome, though.